# Server not sending data after data has already been sent

Tags: c#, tcp

I'm working on a project where I need to send a request to a server then have the server reply with data based on the request(in JSON format), It's kind of working, except after the first reply it doesn't reply again, I'm using [SimpleTcp](https://github.com/BrandonPotter/SimpleTCP) for the client and server. (I'm not sure if the server isn't sending the reply, or if the client just not accepting it, I don't really know how to tell)

Here's the client code:

```
public TType GetReply<TType>()
    { 
        var requestJson = this.ToJson(); // 'this' is the request class which holds the request information and data
        var reply = Client.client.WriteLineAndGetReply(requestJson, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

        while (reply == null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Waiting for not null");
        }

        while (string.IsNullOrEmpty(reply.MessageString))
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("WAITING");
        }
        var str = reply.MessageString.Substring(0, reply.MessageString.Length - 1); // SimpleTcp adds a delimiter by default, this is to remove it
        Debug.WriteLine("JSON: " + str);
        var data = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RequestReply>(str).RequestedData;

        return data.ToObject<TType>();
    }
```

Here's the server code:

```
static void HandleIncomingData(Message e)
    {
        string reply = "";
        var formattedData = e.MessageString.Substring(0, e.MessageString.Length - 1); // SimpleTcp adds a delimiter by default, this is to remove it
        var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Request>(formattedData);

        Console.WriteLine(formattedData);
        Console.WriteLine($"'{data.RequestValues["request"]}' Request");

        switch (data.RequestValues["request"].ToString())
        {
            default:
                reply = CommandHandler.HandleDBRequest(data.RequestValues).ToJson();
                break;

            case "EnterRoom":
                server.ConnectedUsers.Add(new ConnectedUser(e.TcpClient, (int)(long)data.RequestValues["id"]));
                Console.WriteLine($"Client Connected in Room [{data.RequestValues["id"]}] || {e.TcpClient.Ip()}");
                break;  
        }

        Console.WriteLine(reply);
        Console.WriteLine(data.Reply);
        if (data.Reply) e.ReplyLine(reply); // Not sending more than 1 reply
    }
```

### Just a few notes:

`data.RequestValues` is a dictionary that holds the request data (If it was a login request it would hold the email and password for example)

`data.Reply` is a bool for checking if the server should reply to the request (I have confirmed that it is true in the cases where it doesn't reply)

The reason I use JsonConvert instead of `.ToJson();` or `.FromJson();` in some cases is just for testing purposes and I forgot to change it back.

Sorry if I let out any information, kind of new to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Is your code handling the communication protocols correctly?

For example, after receiving the information from the server, is the server waiting for you to confirm you got the data?

If you are building your own client and server in C# then you can take a look into an old post I made (October 15, 2010) in which I wrote a client and a server in C which used Vigenere Cipher: http://www.acarlstein.com/?p=891

If you take a look to the code, you will see that there is a whole communication protocol implemented:

```
#define CODE_FAIL                           '0FAIL'
#define CODE_OK                             '1OK'

#define CODE_HELLO                      '100HELLO'
#define CODE_WELCOME                    '101WELCOME'
#define CODE_REQ_SERVER_NAME    '102REQ_SERVER_NAME'

#define CODE_MSG                            '200MSG'

#define CODE_DATA                           '300DATA'
#define CODE_EOF                            '301EOF'
#define CODE_PUT                          '302PUT'
#define CODE_REQUEST_FILENAME   '303REQ_FILENAME'
#define CODE_REQUEST_ENCRYPT  '304REQ_ENCRYPT'
#define CODE_ENCRYPT                    '305ENCRYPT'
#define CODE_REQUEST_FILE     '306REQUEST_FILE'


#define CODE_CMD                            '400CMD'
#define CODE_LS                             '401LS'

#define CODE_ERROR            '500ERROR'
#define CODE_ERROR_LS                   '501ERROR_LS'
#define CODE_ERROR_CREAT_FILE '502ERROR_CREAT_FILE'

#define CODE_EXIT                           '600EXIT'
```

So, if you are waiting for more information from the server and not getting it, it means that you are supposed to send something to tell the server to continue sending you information.

Comment: As far as I know, there is nothing like that in SimpleTcp and I haven't written anything to do that, I'll check if it does have something like that

Answer (score 0):

<del>I found the issue, I realized none of it is async, so it was saying it got the data before it actually arrived and that caused some problems, got it working now!</del>

EDIT: Seems it has not fixed the issue, I'm still only getting 1 reply from the server.

EDIT2: I have fixed the issue (and confirmed it) this time, I had something else listening for data as well, and the data was going there.